# Why singlar form 'that was' has been used in "the scuffles and yelps coming from the whirl of fists that was Neville, Crabbe, and Goyle"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> “Come on, Harry!" Hermione screamed, leaping onto her seat to watch as Harry sped straight at Snape -- she didn't even notice Malfoy and Ron rolling around under her seat, or the scuffles and yelps coming from the whirl of fists **that was** Neville, Crabbe, and Goyle.

My take to this is that the clause "*that was Neville, Crabbe, and Goyle*" modifies '**fists**', so "**that were**" should be used in this case. In my opinion, the sentence could have been written:

1. ... *the scuffles and yelps coming from the whirl of fists that were Neville, Crabbe, and Goyle.*

**or**

2. ... *the scuffles and yelps coming from the whirl of fists that were Neville's, Crabbe's, and Goyle's.*

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ***whirl* of fists** is the antecedent noun phrase. If they were incinerated by a malevolent wizard, you could say "the pile of ashes that was Neville, Crabbe, and Goyle". The phrase establishes an identity relationship. They are the pile of ashes. They are the whirl of fists. The metonymy reduces them to a salient attribute of their being.

> We were led to the row of cots that was the field hospital.

It's a way of saying "It was hardly a hospital". It was nothing but a row of cots.

At that moment, Neville, Crabbe, and Goyle were nothing but a whirl of fists.

Comment: Great answer! It's my first time to know that the antecedent can be a noun phrase. Usually I only see a single word as the antecedent.